# Excluding directory

Tags: python, django, static-analysis, pyflakes

I am working on a django project and am trying to run pyflakes on an app in it. I need to exclude the "migrations" directory from pyflakes.

For pep8 I can do

```
pep8 --exclude=migrations app_name
```

Is there any similar way for pyflakes?

I couldn't find any proper documentation for pyflakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pyflakes supports a list of files or directories; no "exclude" option

Here's an equivalent:

```
pep8 `find app_name | egrep -v migrations`
```

pyflakes manpage: http://man.cx/?page=pyflakes&do%5Bgo%5D=go

Comment: pyflakes `find app_name/* | egrep -v migrations`. It worked with a slight modification. Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

Use [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) tool instead - it is a wrapper around `pyflakes`, `pep8` and `mccabe`.

Besides other features, it has an `--exclude` option:

```
--exclude=patterns    exclude files or directories which match these comma
                      separated patterns (default:
                      .svn,CVS,.bzr,.hg,.git,__pycache__)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i was trying to do this with pyflakes

Comment: @user3148949 believe me, `flake8` is much more powerful.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the `pylint` tool, but it's rather slow. Pyflakes is *fast*!  Thanks for posting about `flake8`, I'll check that out right now.

Comment: To accomplish the original ask with `flake8` use this command: `$ flake8 --exclude=*/migrations/*`

Comment: @respondcreate : this should be the accepted answer, works with Windows too.